# How to aggregate values of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series, multi-index, cumsum

#### Data manipulation using pandas

Anyone having bright ways to manipulate the values of concatenated pandas series to find total counts?

---

Current data (type: `pandas.core.series.Series`) 
FYI, this data is generated by using 'groupby' function from the raw data.

```
date          device        
2015-07-08    a         0        
              b         0        
              c         0        
              d         1        
2015-07-09    a         0        
              c         1         
              d         1        
2015-07-10    a         1        
              b         1        
              c         1
```

Expected result (type: `pandas.core.series.Series`)
Value of each device denotes the total number of counts up to date A.
As an example, total(2015-07-10, c) = 2 because (2015-07-09, c) = 1 and (2015-07-10, c) = 1

```
date          device    
2015-07-08    a         0
              b         0
              c         0
              d         1
2015-07-09    a         0
              c         1 
              d         2
2015-07-10    a         1
              b         1
              c         2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by second level:

```
dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-08','2015-07-08','2015-07-08','2015-07-08',
                          '2015-07-09','2015-07-09','2015-07-09',
                          '2015-07-10','2015-07-10','2015-07-10'])
devices = ['a','b','c','d','a','c','d','a','b','c']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(dates, devices)), names=['date', 'device'])
s = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1], index= idx)
print (s)
date        device
2015-07-08  a         0
            b         0
            c         0
            d         1
2015-07-09  a         0
            c         1
            d         1
2015-07-10  a         1
            b         1
            c         1
dtype: int64

print (s.groupby(level=1).cumsum())
date        device
2015-07-08  a         0
            b         0
            c         0
            d         1
2015-07-09  a         0
            c         1
            d         2
2015-07-10  a         1
            b         1
            c         2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I didn't know `cumsum()` before. Thank you very much! This is exactly what I want.